# PowerShell: Remove duplicated items from array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, duplicates, unique

I am trying to locate discrepancies in BIND DNS records.  I would like to output a CSV file that only has those discrepancies.  I have a CSV file that has all records from all locations in BIND (ns.prvt, ns.pub, common, includes).  What I'm trying to figure out is how to output a CSV that only shows the discrepancies.  For 2 records to be considered a discrepancy, they must meet the following criteria:

1. Both records have the same RecordName and RecordType.
2. Both records have different Data or TTL.
3. Both records come from different locations.

I am almost there with the following script but it keeps showing me a couple of rows that don't necessarily meet the above criteria.

```
$Records = Import-Csv C:\Temp\Domain_ALL.csv | Select * | Sort Data,Location
$RecordsRev = @()
$Records | % {
    $Record = $_
    $Records | % {
        $DataFE = $_
        If (
        ([string]($Record | ? {($_.RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName)}).RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName) -and 
        ([string]($Record | ? {($_.RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName)}).RecordType -eq $DataFE.RecordType) -and 
        ([string]($Record | ? {($_.RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName)}).Location -ne $DataFE.Location) -and 
        (([string]($Record | ? {($_.RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName)}).Data -ne $DataFE.Data) -or 
        ([string]($Record | ? {($_.RecordName -eq $DataFE.RecordName)}).TTL -ne $DataFE.TTL))
        ) {
            $RecordsRev += $_
        }
    }
}
$RecordsRev | Export-Csv C:\Temp\Domain_Discrepancies.csv -NoType
```

The results that I get are:

```
RecordName RecordType Data                           TTL Location
---------- ---------- ----                           --- --------
domain.com TXT        "MS=abc1234566"                600 Includes
domain.com TXT        "MS=abc1234566"                600 Common  
domain.com TXT        "site-verification=abcd1234"   600 Includes
domain.com TXT        "site-verification=abcd1234"   600 Common  
www        CNAME      somedomain.com.test.           600 Includes
www        CNAME      somedomain.com.                600 Common
```

The results that I expect are:

```
RecordName RecordType Data                           TTL Location
---------- ---------- ----                           --- -------- 
www        CNAME      somedomain.com.test.           600 Includes
www        CNAME      somedomain.com.                600 Common
```

How do I delete all duplicated rows in the array?  This is different from "Select * -unique" as I don't want to keep any row that contains the duplicated information.

EDIT:  I think the main problem is that, since the script checks each record against every record in the CSV, it technically is a discrepancy.  For example, in the below table, record 1 meets the criteria to be a discrepancy because it differs from record 4.  However, since record 1 is the same as record 2, it should actually be omitted from the results.

```
RecordNumber RecordName RecordType Data                           TTL Location
------------ ---------- ---------- ----                           --- --------
1            domain.com TXT        "MS=abc1234566"                600 Includes
2            domain.com TXT        "MS=abc1234566"                600 Common  
3            domain.com TXT        "site-verification=abcd1234"   600 Includes
4            domain.com TXT        "site-verification=abcd1234"   600 Common  
5            www        CNAME      somedomain.com.test.           600 Includes
6            www        CNAME      somedomain.com.                600 Common
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kyle

Comment: How is record 1 the same as record 3?

Comment: Oops.  I meant that record 1 is the same as record 2.  Edited.  Thank you.

Comment: I still have the same question. The `Location` column between record 1 and 2 are different. Hence they're not duplicates, according to your criteria.

Comment: I only want records to show up if they meet the following criteria:  
1. Both records have the same RecordName and RecordType.  
2. Both records have different Data or TTL.
3. Both records come from different locations.

Comment: Right, so 1 and 2 would both be listed, since they meet your criteria (location is different).

Comment: The criteria is all "AND" statements:  "(RecordNames are Equal AND RecordTypes are Equal) AND (Data are different OR TTL are different) AND (Locations are different).

Comment: That was not clear to me from what you wrote earlier. But it seems you have a solution so I will bow out.

Comment: I appreciate your questions and assistance.  I kind of figured that my long-winded explanation wasn't going to be very clear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the help of someone who deleted their post...  Here is the script that I am using now to find all records that meet ALL of the following criteria:

1. Both records have the same RecordName and RecordType.  -AND
2. Both records have different Data or TTL.  -AND
3. Both records come from different locations.

   ```
   $Records = Import-Csv C:\Temp\Domain_ALL.csv | Select * | Sort Data,Location
   $Discrepancies = @()
   $GoodRecords = @()
   $BadRecords = @()

   $Records | ForEach-Object { 

       # for each record $_, compare it against every other record..
       foreach ($R in $Records) {

           # if Both records have the same RecordName and RecordType.. 
           if (($_.RecordName -eq $R.RecordName) -and ($_.RecordType -eq $R.RecordType)) {

               # and if Both records come from different locations..
               if ($_.Location -ne $R.Location) {

                   # if Both records have the same Data and TTL then they are considered good:
                   if (($_.Data -eq $R.Data) -and ($_.TTL -eq $R.TTL)) {
                       $GoodRecords += $_
                   }
                   Else{
                       # if Both records have different Data or TTL then they are considered bad:
                       $BadRecords += $_
                   }
               }
           }
       }

   } 

   ForEach ($BadRecord in $BadRecords){
       If (($GoodRecords -notcontains $BadRecord)){
           $Discrepancies += $BadRecord
       }
   }
   $Discrepancies | Select * -Unique | Sort RecordName,Location,Data | ft
   ```